Find the sum of infinite series: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\beta \, n)^n}{n!} $
I am looking for the sum of an infinite series:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\beta \, n)^n}{n!} $$
where $\beta$ is a constant between $0$ and $1$. I know that if $\beta < 1/e$, the series converges, otherwise it diverges.
Edit:
Thank you for all your suggestions. Lambert-W function is really interesting (and surprisingly useful). I need to study it more carefully though I had used it once before (as a solution to a queueing problem using complex analysis).
I am sorry for not describing the background etc. for this question. This is my first time to post a question and thought to make it simple is the best way. But I did learn quite a lot from this forum over the past years.
The detailed background of my question is too complicated and I will try to make it simple. I was trying to solve an engineering queueing problem (estimating a port's capacity with multiple berths and channels with certain operation rules). Basic assumption is using exponential distribution to model the ships' dwell times (a commonly used assumption due to exponential distribution's elegant analytical properties). I will not describe the details of problem setup and formulation, and the method using busy periods (a method commonly used to analyze renewal-process related problems). But eventually the calculation ends up at estimating the sums of a few infinite series, all can be converted into the form of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\beta n)^n/n!$.
Despite knowing too little, I strongly believe this has a closed-form solution. I understand that it diverges if $\beta$ is too large. Further analysis and search shows that it converges if $|\beta|<1/e$ (in my problem $\beta>0$ for sure, that's why I said it converged if $\beta<1/e$).
Further thinking led me to approximate it using Stirling's approximation to eliminate the factorial (understanding that it is not accurate when $n=0$), and it turned out to be $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\beta e)^n/\sqrt{2\pi n}$. I still have no way to find this sum, but can further approximate it by an integral: $\int_{x=0.5}^{\infty} (\beta e)^x/\sqrt{2\pi x}$. This one, even if I can't derive by myself, I can try Matlab's symbolic toolbox to calculate the integral. I stopped there coz the remaining job is a little tedious and I let my student finish. I understand this is a really bad solution and probably no use for any of you reading this post. But that's how I attempted to tackle the problem.
Again, i appreciate all your replies!

As an FYI, MSE is not a "do my (home)work for me" site. Such posts (e.g. "PSQs") will often be downvoted & closed. If you want meaningful help, please [edit] your post to include relevant context (see here for more), such as your work/attempts, the problem's source, where specifically you're stuck, what you do/don't understand & have learned recently, & so on. If need be, this is helpful for formatting math/LaTeX, & Approach0 is nice for searching up past questions.

The series is a derivative of the Lambert W-function and can be stated as: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^n , \beta^n}{n!} = \frac{W(-\beta)}{1 + W(-\beta)}. $$

@Leucippus. Nice, short and elegant ! Cheers :-)

Take away the first term of http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.13.E5_2
